# Separating OneDrive for Business from the main content database

Tags: sql-server, onedrive-for-business, infrastructure

I would like to separate the OneDrive for Business capability (we're running 2013 on-premises) to another, high capacity server. Reason for this is that we expect tens of terabytes of usage on OneDrive for Business, and our current SAN storage for the farm is only 5 TB, which is plenty for the sites but not enough for user storage.

Since the actual data is kept in SQL in a content database, should I install SQL on the large-storage-capacity server, then recreate the mysites site collection in a new database on that server? Or is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i understand you want move the MYSite(OneDrive for Business is the default document library in a user's My Sites) content Database on new SQL Server which will have more space.

1. Install the same version of SQL Server on new server
2. Set the permission on new sql server for SharePoint accounts
3. now detach the MySite content DB from Mysite web app
4. Move them on new Sql Server
5. Attach databases from new Server to MySite web app
6. test.